# Average Rate of Change From Graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, slope

I'm doing my pre-calculus homework and I cannot find an answer to this problem in my book or anywhere. I am give the following graph

[image: graph]

The question is the following:

Estimate the average rate of change from 
$t = 1950$ to $t = 1960$, from $t = 1960$ to $t = 1970$, and from $t = 1970$ to $t = 1980$.

The issue is I don't know how you are supposed to calculate average rate of change if I can't find the $y$-value based on the graph. I know how to calculate the average rate of change if I know the points/pairs with $$\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$
This is all I am given, no other values or tables.

Comment: It is the slope of the line going through the two points.

Comment: I am aware of that, the question is how do I calculate the slope of two points without the y values of the points. The graph is not detailed enough to be able to estimate the y values and the homework expects an exact answer.

Comment: The problem asks for an estimate, so you can estimate that $4000$ doctorates were awarded to women in $1970$ and $9500$ were awarded in $1980$, from which you can then determine an approximate slope.

Comment: The y values are those numbers that run along the vertical axis of the graph. For example, approximately $4000$ women earned their PhDs in 1970.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the graph above we can conclude the following (some values of $x$  don't have an easy to identify $y$ value on the graph because the interval of the y-axis is large).

[image]

Comment: Your answer makes sense but I don't exactly what they expect except guessing "known" points because I got the answer key and the correct answers are 1950-1960=20, 1960-1970=300, 1970-1980=450

Comment: Well, I made some changes after enlarging the graph. I assume that the vertical distance is divided into 4 ticks, so you get 0,500,1000,1500,2000,2500,3000,3500,4000,etc. I have not been able to fit the numbers of the 1st and last values as far as I can see. Specially the first, I don't see how it could be 20 at all.